# Persisting Child entity when using mappedBy in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, hibernate-onetomany

My DB schema has two tables :- `Rule Table` and `Rule Scope` table.
Rule Table columns (`rule_id` Primary Key, .....) and Rule Scope columns (`rule_id` Foreign key , `Scope_id` (**NOT Auto generated Id, Can repeat for different rule_id**)
Rule Scope Primary key is combination of `rule_id` and `Scope_id`.

My `RULE` Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RULE")
public class Rule implements IEntity {

@Column(name = "RULE_ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int ruleId;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="rule")
private Set<RuleScope> ruleScope=new HashSet<RuleScope>();
```

`Rule Scope` Entity:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RULE_SCOPE")
public class RuleScope {

@Embeddable
public static class Id implements Serializable{
    @Column(name = "RULE_ID")
    private int ruleId;
    @Column(name = "SCOPE_ID")
    private int scopeId;
}

@EmbeddedId
private Id id = new Id();

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "RULE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Rule rule;
```

I have following questions:-
When I am trying to save the Rule ,  but it is not persisting the Child Entity. it is giving 0 for Rule Id when persisting the Rule Scope which is violating the Foreign Key Constraint.  But when i use @JoinColumn the it is working. Please help me to persist the `Rule Scope` while persisting `Rule` and using `mappedBy`.

Comment: Have you tried to: @OneToMany(mappedBy="rule", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<RuleScope> ruleScope=new HashSet<RuleScope>();

Comment: It is giving the same exception

Comment: I am currently using OpenJPA, and cannot be very helpful. I would try ManyToMany, PrimaryKeyJoinColum, or JOIN Strategy.... You can review later, and change it back.

Comment: @JamaDjafarov... I am able to resolve the issue noww...and its working but now when i am using mappedBy it is not persisting the Child entities(searched one net it shows that that parent is not the owner) but if i use @JoinColumn it is persisting both Parent and Child. Can you please clarify as how to get the parent and child persisted when using `mappedBy`

Comment: I would say, try in RULE: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="rule") . Also, if it doesn't work, try a different approach. I noticed when I try a different approach, in most cases it helps to find the issue.

Comment: @JamaDjafarov i have already tried tht Cascading, it is not persisting , everytime it is giving newly created Parent entity Id as 0. What is the other approach you are suggesting? Is it of that helper functions?

Comment: try ManyToMany, or you can try JOIN Strategy - class RuleScope extends Rule

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Rule Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RULE")
public class Rule implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RULE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int ruleId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.rule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RuleScope> ruleScope = new HashSet<RuleScope>(0);

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()
}
```

RULE_SCOPE Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RULE_SCOPE")
public class RuleScope implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    // Generate Getters, Setters
}
```

RULE_SCOPE composite PK:

```
@Embeddable
public class Id implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RULE_ID", , nullable = false)
    private Rule rule;

    @Column(name = "SCOPE_ID")
    private int scopeId;

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the update..i corrected and it started working. I used a different approach..